# Getting Spring ThreadPoolExecutor in a Service class

Tags: java, spring, threadpool

I created a bean thread pool executor in Application context. I want to use that thread pool executor and run some code in another class which annotated like @Service.

My Application Class

```
public class TestApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {"classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor testAsync() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("TestExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Below class is the where I need to get that thread to execute

```
@Service
public class TastService{
      public void runMyCode(){
         //Here I need to start that thread and then call executor.submit()
      }
}
```

Comment: Don't... Just put `@Async` on the method. Why would you need to submit the thin yourself? If you really need it just autowire a `TaskExecutor` and use it.

Comment: When I used `@Autowire` annotation application failed with an error of cannot bind.

I can't use `@Async` because I want some context data on current thread to the new starting thread. that's why I tried to get the Thread through Spring Boot

Comment: Change the return type of your `@Bean` method to `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and then inject a `TaskExecutor` (not the full type just the interface!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Inject it with Autowire annotation. Notice that if you are using `@Bean` annotation in java config the bean name will be the same as annotated method name unless you are using name property of `@Bean` annotation

```
    @Service
    public class TastService{

         private final Executor testAsync;

         @Autowire
         public TastService(Executor testAsync) {
             this.testAsync = testAsync;
         }

         public void runMyCode(){
            testAsync.submit()
         }
   }
```

Comment: The name has nothing to do with it (it is a fallback).. The type does.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But as far as I know name also could matter in case you have several beans of one type.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the `testAsync` bean from `ApplicationContext` in the service file.

Inside the service class,

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@Service
public class TastService{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void runMyCode(){
        //Here I need to start that thread and then call executor.submit()
        Executor executor = (Executor) applicationContext
                .getBean("testAsync");
    }
}
```

But you need to also take care that, `testAsync` method is loaded first during application start and then `TastService` is loaded. Or else it would fail. This can be achieved by adding `@DependsOn`([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html))

Hope this helps